# Mysqljs pool и настройки

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

1)Что означает настройка connectionLimit и что происходит когда количество соединений достигает 11.

2)Нужно ли "Отпускать соединение" (pool.end и т.п.) в примере как показано ниже?

3)Не могу разобраться почему на сайте mysql модуль использует очень много RAM при небольшой нагрузке. Возможно ли это из-за того, что не реализован пункт 2?

4)checkExpirationInterval и expiration, что это за звери?

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
checkExpirationInterval: 900000,// How frequently expired sessions will be cleared; milliseconds. 
expiration: 86400000,// The maximum age of a valid session; milliseconds. 
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  res.send('Hello World!'+rows.solution);
});
  
});
```

Comment: Возможно кто-нибудь добрый и переведет вам доки, но лучше бы вы сами почитали: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql, https://github.com/chill117/express-mysql-session. 2-3. Я с этими библиотеками не работал, но из общих соображений - да.

Comment: Я не нашел там нужной информации. Про експерсс-сессию спасибо, видимо осталось от старого модуля

Answer (score 0):

> 1)Что означает настройка connectionLimit и что происходит когда количество соединений достигает 11.

`connectionLimit` - максимальное количество соединений с базой данных, которое может содержать пул. Это означает, что при `connectionLimit = 10` пул **никогда** не будет содержать 11 соединений.

В то же время, при достижении лимита соединений, операции вроде `pool.getConnection` будут ждать пока какое-либо соединение не будет возвращено в пул. Это плавно подводит нас ко второму вопросу.

> 2)Нужно ли "Отпускать соединение" (pool.end и т.п.) в примере как показано ниже?

Да, соединения, которые больше не нужны обязательно нужно возвращать в пул, иначе вы очень быстро исчерпаете его ресурс, а все кто ждут свободного соединения с базой будут оставаться в таком состоянии неопределенно долго. Вот пример того, как правильно работать с пулом соединений:

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    pool  = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 10,
        host: 'example.org',
        user: 'foo',
        password: 'secret',
        database: 'my_db'
    });

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
        // Необходимо освободить соединение сразу же, как только оно больше не нужно.
        connection.release();
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

       console.log(rows.solution);
    });
});
```

Что касается [`pool.end`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool) - то у этого метода совсем другое предназначение. Согласно [документации](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#closing-all-the-connections-in-a-pool), этот метод закрывает все соединения и запрещает пулу выдавать новые.

> 3)Не могу разобраться почему на сайте mysql модуль использует очень много RAM при небольшой нагрузке. Возможно ли это из-за того, что не реализован пункт 2?

Сказать хоть что-то без отладки и профилирования кода приложения невозможно.

> 4)checkExpirationInterval и expiration, что это за звери?

Эти поля не имеют непосредственного отношения к пулу соединений MySQL, как следствие, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос.